# Laravel query scope has against dynamic value

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm struggling to come up with the right mix of builder vs raw SQL that addresses my need.  **I have a setting that allows a user to configure `X` number of `TournamentQuizmasters` be required for `X` number of `Teams`.  I need to do this calculation on a MySQL level for efficiency**, so I can quickly query all eligible teams.  I have other query scopes in place to determine what an eligible team is (e.g. `withEnoughPlayers()`).

This code doesn't work, but I think it communicates my intentions.

```
// A collection of Teams
class TeamSet extends Model {
    public function scopeWithEnoughQuizmastersBasedOnTeamCount(Builder $q, Tournament $tournament)
    {
        // Pull only the groups that bring enough quizmasters.  The required number
        // of quizmasters is based off of the number of teams they're bringing.
        return $q->whereHas('group', function (Builder $q) use ($tournament) {
                $q->has(
                    'tournamentQuizmasters',
                    '>=',
                    DB::raw('FLOOR(('.$tournament->settings->quizmastersToRequireByTeamCount().' * '.$q->selectRaw('COUNT(*)')->teams()->withEnoughPlayers($tournament)->toSql().') / '.$tournament->settings->teamCountToRequireQuizmastersBy().')')
                );
        });
    }
}
```

Running this query I get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::teams()` which I believe is because of the `selectRaw()` proceeding it.  I also don't think I can actually call `->teams()` the way I am here, but I'm a bit blind from how I should be altering this to obtain the results I'm looking for.

**How can I perform this dynamic expression while utilizing query builder so I can utilize my scopes?**

I'm using Laravel 5.7

#### Models & Relations

```
class TeamSet {
    public function group() : BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
    }
    public function teams() : HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Team::class)
    }
}

class Team {
    public function teamSet() : BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(TeamSet::class)
    }
}

class Group {

    public function tournamentQuizmasters() : HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TournamentQuizmaster::class);
    }

    public function teams() : HasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Team::class, TeamSet::class);
    }
}

class Tournament {
    public function teamSets() : HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TeamSet::class);
    }

    public function teams() : HasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Team::class, TeamSet::class);
    }
}

class TournamentQuizmaster {
    public function group() : BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
    }

    public function tournament() : BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Tournament::class);
    }
}
```

Description of models:

- `TeamSet` - a single entity that represents a collection of teams.  This empowers our users to be able to use the same set of teams for multiple tournaments.
- `Team` - A collection of players
- `Group` - The group name.  This is used in other places within the app, but every `TeamSet` belongs to a group.
- `Tournament` - Pretty self-explanatory
- `TournamentQuizmaster` - A referee or judge for the tournament.  Each group needs to bring X of these based on their number of teams

**$tournament->settings**

This is stored as json in the database, but cast to an object so I have a reasonable place to keep default values.  Here's a snippet of that class:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Fluent;

class Settings extends Fluent
{
    const DEFAULT_MAXIMUM_PLAYERS_PER_TEAM = 5;
    const DEFAULT_MINIMUM_PLAYERS_PER_TEAM = 3;

    public function __construct($attributes = [])
    {
        if ($attributes !== null) {
            parent::__construct($attributes);
        }
    }

    public function shouldRequireQuizmasters() : bool
    {
        return $this->get('requireQuizmasters', 'none') != 'none';
    }

    public function shouldRequireQuizmastersByGroup() : bool
    {
        return $this->get('requireQuizmasters', null) == 'group';
    }

    public function quizmastersToRequireByGroup() : int
    {
        return $this->get('quizmastersToRequireByGroup', 1);
    }

    public function setQuizmastersToRequireByGroup(int $quizmasterCount)
    {
        $this->quizmastersToRequireByGroup = $quizmasterCount;
    }

    public function shouldRequireQuizmastersByTeamCount() : bool
    {
        return $this->get('requireQuizmasters', null) == 'team_count';
    }

    public function quizmastersToRequireByTeamCount() : int
    {
        return $this->get('quizmastersToRequireByTeamCount', 1);
    }
```

The json stored in the database ends up looking like:

```
{"collectShirtSizes":"1","collectQuizmasterPreferences":"1","allowsGuestPlayers":true,"minimumPlayersPerTeam":3,"maximumPlayersPerTeam":6,"requireQuizmasters":"group","quizmastersToRequireByGroup":1,"quizmastersToRequireByTeamCount":1,"teamCountToRequireQuizmastersBy":2}
```

Comment: Share your tables schema and a little more detail about what you are trying to achieve? And also explain the relationship of tables

Comment: The table schemas all follow the Laravel standards, so `Tournament` maps to the tournaments table, `TeamSet` has a `team_sets` table with a `tournament_id` column, etc.  I don't think any of the columns outside of the relations are relevant so I'm hesitant to overload this with info that may not be needed.

I'm updating it with a description of the models as well as some additional comments/context.

Comment: How many rows in the largest table?  What queries will you perform?

Comment: Great question, less than 1k and only a few hundred will be added each year.

Comment: Is `settings` an attribute or a relationship?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir An attribute, it's a json field that gets mapped to a non-model object

Comment: Can you add the result of `dd($tournament->settings);`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I've included a copy of the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able do some things like this using the subSelect technique in the following article.
https://reinink.ca/articles/dynamic-relationships-in-laravel-using-subqueries

Based on that you could get the count of teams with enough players added to your Group query and compare it to the Tournament Quiz masters count. I hopefully I understood your query enough. Something like this maybe.

```
/// In Group
public function scopeHasRequiredAmount(Builder $builder, Tournament $tournament)
{
    return $builder->withCount('tournamentQuizmasters')
        ->teamsWithEnoughPlayersCount()
        ->havingRaw(
            'tournamentQuizmasters_count > FLOOR((' . $tournament->settings->quizmastersToRequireByTeamCount() .
            '* teams_with_enough_players_count ) /'
            . $tournament->settings->teamCountToRequireQuizmastersBy() . ')'
        );
}

/// adds count of teams with enough players to query
public function scopeTeamsWithEnoughPlayersCount(Builder $builder, Tournament $tournament)
{
    return $builder->addSubSelect('teams_with_enough_players_count', Team::selectRaw('count(*)')
        ->whereColumn('groups.id', 'teams.group_id')
        ->withEnoughPlayers($tournament)
    );
}

/// In Teamset
function scopeWithEnoughQuizmastersBasedOnTeamCount(Builder $builder, $tournament)
{
    return $builder->whereHas('group', function (Builder $q) use ($tournament) {
        $q->hasRequiredAmount($tournament);
    });

}
```

Comment: The SQL this generates looks really solid for what I'm trying to do, thanks for the review.  I needed to switch the `whereRaw()` to `havingRaw() in order to utilize  'tournament_quizmasters_count' in the condition.  My test is failing, so I'm still debugging the exact logic changes needed.

Comment: Yep, this nailed it.  Thanks!  I realized the reason this wasn't still doing what I needed was related to data integrity.